# CORS Preflight not working with SignalR and IIS using Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, iis, cors, signalr

So I am trying to establish a connection with SignalR but I receive the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://SAME.NETWORK:SOMEPORT/PortalCommunicationsHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

This is my service code:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalRService {
  public data: dataProfile[];

  private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;

  public startConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl('http://SAME.NETWORK:SOMEPORT/PortalCommunicationsHub')
    .build();

    this.hubConnection
    .start()
    .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
    .catch(err => console.log('Error starting connection: ' + err));
  }

  public availableDoorProfilesListener = () => {
    this.hubConnection.on('availableDoorProfiles', (data) => {
      this.data = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

And I call the service like this:

```
export class DoorProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  options: Option[];

  selectedOption: Option;

  constructor(public signalRService: SignalRService, private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.signalRService.startConnection();
    this.signalRService.availableProfilesListener();
  }

}
```

The server CORS settings:

```
public const string CORS_ALL = "AllCors";


            options.AddPolicy(name: CORS_ALL,
                    corsOptions =>
                        corsOptions
                            .WithOrigins("*"));

 

        app.UseCors(configuration["CorsPolicy"] ?? Startup.CORS_LOCALHOST);
```

It seems correct however I'm getting that pesky CORS message.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: The error message tells you everything you need to know: Credentialed requests are incompatible with the use of the wildcard (`*`). You'll need to configure CORS to allow select origins rather than all origins with `*`. More about this in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards

Comment: You'll also need to modify your CORS configuration to allow credentialed requests.

Comment: Set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to a specific origin, e.g. 'http://localhost:3000' or a list of whitelisted origins that are allowed to access your server. Note that the origin must specify the protocol, domain and port.

Comment: The backend developer here fixed the connection issue, it was on the server. Now my issue is that I connect but get no response.

Comment: Inspect network requests and responses using tools such as Fiddler or browser developer tools. This can help you see if the SignalR communication is happening correctly and if there are any error messages in the response.

Answer (score 0):

It might be your policy name:

```
app.UseCors(configuration["CorsPolicy"] ?? Startup.CORS_LOCALHOST);
```

From the code provided above, you are using : "`AllCors`"